# Domain problem. Strange

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, hosting, domain, dedicated-server

We have domain http://www.armtimes.com.

Almost always we can't access domain with www or without. Depends when we trying. Random time.

Also ping doesn't go. When I change in hosts file and setting (IP) armtimes.com, site open's normally..

Sometimes domain is working normally..

I think this is Domain related problem. What can be this?

**Edit:** Half of the problem was fixed: named was not started automatically after restart. I have started named service, and now work's. But I can't access site via www. Without www work's normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not appear to load for me. The problem could be with DNS caching. Sometimes it takes 24 hours for the correct DNS settings to propagate around the internet. Also sometimes, the old DNS settings will reside on your computer unless you flush the dns.

Have you configured an A record to point to your IP address?

Comment: We have written to support to change DNS. This was done 4-5 days ago.

Comment: Site sometimes work's normally. For example 3 hours ago.. But now... Doesn't work with or without www.

Comment: it strikes me that the problem is with your DNS provider. Who are you using? Also, what did you tell them to change the DNS settings to?

Comment: I have gave him our server IP's and nameservers. We are using Enom for Domain.

Comment: when you edit your hosts file, you short-circuit the DNS settings.

Comment: My post was edited.

Comment: www.armtimes.com works for me. You may want to check the fact that ns1.armtimes.com looks good but ns2.armtimes.com does not. Maybe you have to flush the dns on the computer you are using the test the website.

Comment: I have tested for my internet provider. It looks like problems only on my provider.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 7. Same problem in other computer with same Internet Provider.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that there is a problem with your DNS Servers/Nameservers. According to OpenDNS:

```
`Nameserver trace for www.armtimes.com:

Looking for who is responsible for root zone and followed a.root-servers.net.
Looking for who is responsible for com and followed b.gtld-servers.net.
Looking for who is responsible for armtimes.com and followed ns1.armtimes.com.
Nameservers for www.armtimes.com:

ns1.armtimes.com returned (SERVFAIL)
ns2.armtimes.com returned (SERVFAIL)`
```

Do you definatley have a DNS Server running on ns1.armtimes.com and ns2.armtimes.com?

Comment: DNS configuration was done by iweb.com support. Can be this server related problem? I don't think so, because when I point in my hosts armtimes.com domain to my IP, website works.

Comment: I would contact them and ask them to look into it. I'm fairly confident that it is a problem with your DNS Server.

Comment: My post was edited. Check it.

Comment: It's working for me, now. The reason www.armtimes.com isn't working will be something to do with either your ISP's DNS cache, or your local DNS Cache.

Comment: You should probably look at getting ns2.armtimes.com fixed, too. That DNS Server isn't currently online.

Answer (score 0):

If you try some of the online DNS diagnostics your DNS is basically screwed or non-existant.

http://www.intodns.com/armtimes.com
http://www.squish.net/dnscheck/

Your two DNS servers are timing out.

Do you have glue records set?

Comment: My post was edited. Check it.

Comment: So what are ns1.linuxgravity.com and ns2.linuxgravity.com?  Those are the servers listed as NS records for armtimes.com at ns1.armtimes.com and ns2.armtimes.com.